# ajax update data content after success without setinterval

Tags: jquery, ajax, setinterval

is there way to update ajax data content after scucess without setinterval
it's make my browser very slow 
here's my code

```
setInterval(function(){
var ajaxurles = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: ajaxurles,
     data:'action=ajax_statics&post_id=<?php echo $post->ID; ?>',
     success:function(data){
    $(".loadajaximge").hide();
    $('.inajaxupdates').empty();
    $(".inajaxupdates").append(data);
    }               
    });
    },9000);
```

Comment: in that case remove the setInterval, wrap it in DOM ready handler..! why' did you add your Ajax inside setInterval btw..?

Comment: but without setInterval will not update the content after first success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would need the use of [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) or [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout). But `setTimeout` would be better than `setInterval`, because with `setInterval`, if your previous ajax request is not complete, and you start another request, there will have multiple requests which would sooner be problematic. 
What you could do is, use `setTimeout`, such as:

```
(function doSomeRequest() {
  $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: ajaxurles,
     data:'action=ajax_statics&post_id=<?php echo $post->ID; ?>',
     success:function(data){    
        $(".loadajaximge").hide();
        $('.inajaxupdates').empty();
        $(".inajaxupdates").append(data);
     },
     complete: function() {
         //call the 'doSomeRequest' when current one is complete
         setTimeout(doSomeRequest, 9000);
     }
  });
})();
```

But with `setTimeout` if your request fails then it would prevent other requests.

Answer (score 0):

use only this much part of the code, no need to setinterval when you want to append the content after an success callback, until and unless you want to make an ajax call again and again using an interval. Use the below code:

```
ajaxurles = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: ajaxurles,
     data:'action=ajax_statics&post_id=<?php echo $post->ID; ?>',
     success:function(data){
    $(".loadajaximge").hide();
    $('.inajaxupdates').empty();
    $(".inajaxupdates").append(data);
    }               
    });
```

**Edited:**

```
ajaxurles = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
setInterval(function(){
$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: ajaxurles,
     data:'action=ajax_statics&post_id=<?php echo $post->ID; ?>',
     success:function(data){
    $(".loadajaximge").hide();
    $('.inajaxupdates').empty();
    $(".inajaxupdates").append(data);
    }               
    });
    },9000);
```

Comment: thank u for quick reply if i use it without setinterval will not update content after ajax success first time

Comment: then you need to use the above code that you are using in your question with slight modifications that i am giving in editing of my answer, if you need to call ajax again and again then the procedure in your question is fine, yes it will slow down the things if you have low bandwidth in your hosting plan.

Comment: still too slow. so there's no way to do that without setinterval ?

Comment: Using the  procedure in your question it is the only best way to do.